# assignment to destructured object property from function parameter list doesn't mutate object

Tags: javascript

is this expected?

```js
const testObj = {
  a: 'hi',
  b: 'there'
}


function destructured_test({a, b}) {
    a = 'bye';
}

console.log(testObj);
destructured_test(testObj);
console.log(testObj);

function test(t) {
    t.a = 'bye';
}

console.log(testObj);
test(testObj);
console.log(testObj);
```

only the function 'test' mutates testObj 'destructured_test' seems to be copying the properties over instead of preserving the reference

Comment: That's how values work. [Why should this work different than your `destructured_test`](https://jsbin.com/pivameb/1/edit?js,console)? See also: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000)

Comment: hmm now I wonder if a and b were objects if they would be passed by reference

Comment: JS is *always* pass by value.

Comment: meh passing a pointer by value is kinda like passing an obj by reference no? that is what it is doing for 'test' function

Comment: but then it goes and makes copies for the destructure, seems wonky

Comment: The value of an object is its reference. So, `f(obj)` is still passing a value. However, inside that function you cannot have `arg =  {new: "object"}` and have that take effect on the passed in parameter. Because you're not manipulating the reference there.

Comment: if a and b were objects then any changes you did to them in destructured_test would be visible in console.log(testObj).

Comment: @James only if changing properties. `a = "hello"` wouldn't do anything outside the function.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant if you added a property to object a or pushed an element into an array b, it would be reflected, but completely redefining a and b would just result in new values for a and b and not do anything to testObj.

Comment: When you destructure function arguments with `foo({ a }) { bar(a) }` This is similar to `foo(_ref) { var a = _ref.a; bar(a) }`  You can check such things by transpiling to ES2015.